# How does Elasticsearch incremental snapshots deal with the deleted docs?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-snapshot

I regularly take a snapshot of my ES cluster in a s3 bucket and so i wanted to know that if i am deleting my old docs from the cluster and regularly adding new docs then after taking a snapshot how does ES deal with this scenario wheather the docs get deleted from my previous snapshots as well or how does ES keep a backup of my docs. Please explain?

Answer (score 5):

When ES takes snapshots, ES doesn't take snapshots of `docs` but rather it takes snapshots of `segments`. Of course, the segments contain the docs.

To understand the concept of incremental, let's take the below example.

Say there's an index called `my_index` with `1 primary shard (shard 0)`. As data gets written to the index, it will create segment file(s) for the shards.

Initially, the index my_index may look like:

```
"my_index"
"consists of shard 0"
"shard 0 consists of segements A,B,C"
```

You take Snapshot S1 of index my_index at time T1.

The snapshot S1 contains the following metadata:

```
Index: my_index
Shards: 0
Segments: A,B,C
And then it will copy the segment files.
```

Now, you index more data. ES merges segements B and C into a new segment D and adds new segment E for new data. 
Once segments are merged, the old segments are deleted from the shard. Same way, when documents are deleted, segment merging happens

Now the shard 0 of index my_index contains segments A,D,E

You take Snapshot S2 of index my_index at time T2.
S2 will check to see what files it will need.

```
It will NOT copy segment A (because it already exists in the repo - this is what is meant by incremental). 
It will copy segment D
it will copy segment E
```

The snapshot S2 contains the following metadata:

```
Index: my_index Shards: 0 Segments: A,D,E
```

**What is incremental here?** 
The incremental nature is for new segment files not necessarily for new data.
For Snapshot S2, segment A was NOT copied because it was already contained in S1.

**When happens when you delete Snapshot S1?**
1. Segments B and C will be deleted since they are no longer being referenced
2. Exclude Segment A since it's being referenced by Snapshot S2

**When happens when you delete index my_index?**
The snapshots will still contain segement files pertaining to my_index allowing you to recover the index anytime.

**What happens when documents are deleted?**
When docs are deleted, eventually the segment files are merged, new segments are created. So when you take a snapshot after document has been deleted, the snapshot will not have the document.

Hope this helps

Comment: @Yash Tandon - in case this answer helped you, would you mind accepting it?

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation! This helped me understand the concept of segments finally