# Is it possible to append (instead of restore) a snapshot of indices?

Tags: elasticsearch, snapshot

Suppose we have some indices in our cluster. I can make a snapshot of my favorite index and I can restore the same index again to my cluster if the same index is not exists or is closed. But what if the index currently exists and I need to add/append extra data/documents to it ?

Suppose I currently have 100000 documents in my index in my server. I create/add 100 documents to my index in my local system  which has the same name, the same mappings and the same settings, the same number of shards and . . ., now I want to add 100 documents to my current index in my server (100000 documents) . What is the best way ?

In MySQL I use export to csv or excel and ... and it is so easy to import or append data to currently existed index.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Append API for Elasticsearch but I suggest to restore indices with temporary name and use [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) to index local data to bigger indices. then delete temporary indices.

also you can use Logstash for this purpose (reindex). build a pipeline which read data from temp indices ([Elasticsearch input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) ) and write data to primary indices ([Elasticsearch output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html))

note: you can't have two indices with the same name in cluster.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65856880/4039725) by Hamid Bayat, :

> Is it possible to append (instead of restore) a snapshot of indices?

Snapshots by nature are incremental i.e append-only. See [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/is-snapshot-incremental/28872/2?u=sandeepkanabar) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58516488/4039725). Thus, if your index has 1000 docs and you snapshot it and later add 100 more docs, then when you trigger another snapshot, only the recently added 100 docs will be snapshotted and not all the 1100. However, `restore is not incremental`. I.e. you cannot restore only those recently added 100 docs. If you restore an index, you restore `all` the docs.

From your description of the question, it seems you are looking for something like: when you add 100 docs to local ES Cluster, you also want those 100 docs to be added in the remote (other) ES Cluster as well. Am I correct?

As for export csv or excel, there's an excellent tool called [es2csv](https://github.com/taraslayshchuk/es2csv) that allows to export data from ES to csv. And then you can use Kibana to import the CSV data. Or use this tool called [Elasticsearch_Loader](https://github.com/Moshe/elasticsearch_loader). You might also want to look at another excellent tool called [elasticdump](https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump)